# Error while calling SharePoint API "_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor"

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, user-profile, pnp, organization-chart

I installed my webpart from this link
https://github.com/moumen100/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-organization-chart

This webpart use pnp.js profiles library to get user profile data and that library calls SharePoint API URL below:

```
_api/sp.userprofiles.peoplemanager/getpropertiesfor
```

After debugging code, I found that calling this API generates http 500 error like below:

[image]

Then when I link through API URL, I get the following error:

[image]

For more information, I have installed `"UserProfile Service Application"` and I started synchronization from Active Directory.

Is there anything missed to call this UserProfile API?